# Does the C# LINQ Aggregate method finish execution once the result can no longer change?

Tags: c#, linq

I know that if I chain `&&` or `||` operators together in the same statement, c# will stop computing the statement and return the appropriate result if it evaluates an expression and no matter what the following expressions are, the result won't change. For instance:

```
var result = false && foo() && bar();
```

In this statement, `foo()` and `bar()` will never get executed since the first expression is false. My question is, will the `Enumerable.Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>` do the same thing when ran over a list of bools or will it evaluate all the expressions regardless? For example:

```
var result = new List<bool>
{
    false,
    foo(),
    bar()
}.Aggregate(true, (acc, x) => acc && x);
```

Comment: the term is "short circuit evaluation"

Comment: `Aggregate()` will iterate over the entire enumerable.

Comment: No, the accumulation function is opaque to `Aggregate` so it must consume the entire sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&&` operator in your example will short circuit, yes.  `x` won't be evaluated any time `acc` is `false`.

Of course, the whole predicate will need to be executed for every element.  `Aggregate` has no possible way of knowing that later executions of it won't change the aggregated value.

Your aggregation function is actually performing an `All` operation on the data set, and if you use the `All` operation, rather than the more general `Aggregate`, it is capable of determining, as soon as a given predicate is `false`, that the result is known and can't change, and that the predicate doesn't need to be invoked on the remaining elements (as does `Or` when a `true` value is found).

Comment: Odd voting pattern...  Seems like the voters don't really understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Pursuant to a different issue, I was using `Aggregate` and needed to exit early if a certain intermediate value occurred, which ended up involving a lot of ternary operators (or a lambda body with `if`) to bypass the aggregation when that value was reached, so I wrote some new extensions to exit early:

```
public static T AggregateWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, T> accumFn, Predicate<T> whileFn) {
    using (var e = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception("At least one element required by AggregateWhile");
        var ans = e.Current;
        while (whileFn(ans) && e.MoveNext())
            ans = accumFn(ans, e.Current);
        return ans;
    }
}

public static TAccum AggregateWhile<TAccum, T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TAccum seed, Func<TAccum, T, TAccum> accumFn, Predicate<TAccum> whileFn) {
    using (var e = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception("At least one element required by AggregateWhile");
        var ans = accumFn(seed, e.Current);
        while (whileFn(ans) && e.MoveNext())
            ans = accumFn(ans, e.Current);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

For your example, you could use it as follows:

```
var result = new List<bool> {
    false,
    foo(),
    bar()
}.AggregateWhile(true, (acc, x) => acc && x, acc => acc);
```

Of course, `foo()` and `bar()` will be executed because a `List<bool>` doesn't defer execution, so only the loop time is saved. But if you had a sequence that does:

```
var result = new List<Func<bool>> { () => false, () => foo(), () => bar() }
             .AggregateWhile(true, (acc, f) => acc && f(), acc => acc);
```

that would skip executing `foo` and `bar`.

The obvious counterpart `AggregateUntil`s are left as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, your Aggregate call will iterate over the whole collection, but the && on each call will short circuit.  Here's an example that might illustrate this:

You can see that in result1, it does stop evaluating x() once it gets a false result.  This is because of short circuiting on acc.

In result2, we've moved acc to the right of the && and it forces x() to be evaluated in all cases.

```
Console.WriteLine("acc && x()");
var result1 = new List<Func<bool>>
{
    () => {Console.WriteLine("One"); return true;},
    () => {Console.WriteLine("Two"); return false;},
    () => {Console.WriteLine("Three"); return false;}
}.Aggregate(true, (acc, x) => acc && x());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("x() && acc");
var result2 = new List<Func<bool>>
{
    () => {Console.WriteLine("One"); return true;},
    () => {Console.WriteLine("Two"); return false;},
    () => {Console.WriteLine("Three"); return false;}
}.Aggregate(true, (acc, x) => x() && acc);
```

Output:

```
acc && x()
One
Two

x() && acc
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: I think it is good to note that while it doesn't evaluate `x()`, it does continue to loop through all elements of the `List<>` while skipping the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Now, *in theory*, the compiler could in-line the Aggregate(), take the lambda, and  integrate it into the inlined Aggregate, and then the optimizer could recognize the early-out potential.

The doubt the current C# compiler's optimizer is anywhere near that aggressive, not do I think anything like that is planned for it, but it's always a possibility.